# Insert lines from a TXT file into a SQL Database using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, database, database-connection

I have a file that contains data from a device, and I need to insert this data into a database. The text file looks like this:

```
10/01/15-20:37:30 = 40.2,25.4,42.3,54.3,70.0,66.6
10/01/15-20:38:26 = 67.3,18.4,30.6,39.3,70.0,66.6
10/01/15-20:39:21 = 74.5,16.8,28.2,36.0,70.0,66.6
10/01/15-20:40:16 = 76.8,16.6,27.6,35.2,70.0,66.6
10/01/15-20:41:12 = 78.1,16.4,27.3,34.9,70.0,66.6
```

And my code currently looks like this:

```
<?php
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "pass";
    $dbname = "dbase";


    // Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    // Check connection
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
    } 
?>

<?PHP

    $file_handle = fopen("datalog.txt", "r");

    while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $parts = explode('  ', $line_of_text);

    print $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";

}

$datainsert = "INSERT INTO reading (val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6, val7, val8, val9, val10) VALUES ($parts[0])"; 

if (mysqli_query($conn, $datainsert)) {
    echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $datainsert . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}


?>

<?php
$conn->close();
?>
```

The error I get is this:

> Error:
>
> INSERT INTO reading (Box_ID, Time_Stamp, Temperature, Humidity, CO_Level, VOC_Reading_UOM, VOC_Reading_V1, VOC_Reading_V2, VOC_Reading_V3, VOC_Reading_V4) VALUES () Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

My database and site do connect without errors, and this page is the only one with problems.  What is going wrong?

Comment: From looking at that error message, you're not adding anything in the `VALUES` part of the SQL. Check that `$parts[0]` contains what you think it contains.

Comment: The error message says it all you are not passing any data in the `VALUES ()` so the query will of course fail

Comment: I put the $parts [0] in the values area because i thought that was where the code was pulling the information from. If you look a little earlier in my code you will see the $parts = explode then it pulls the values out and separates them. So im not properly accessing that information is what you are saying?

Comment: @graphicdesigner88 - yes. You're printing out your SQL statement if it fails, and the `VALUES()` part there shows that there's nothing in `$parts[0]`; or at least, not what you're expecting. Try adding `var_dump($parts)` just after your loop to see what's in there.

Comment: array(1) { [0]=> string(0) "" }  is what appears after i ad the var_dump ($parts)

Comment: 10 fields specified, 1 value provided. where's the other 9?

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be exploding by a string containing two spaces. In your text file, however, your 'fields' are separated by a single space. You should change your call to `explode()` to use a single space (or get fancy and look at `preg_split()`).

Comment: BTW, you're still going to have to do something a bit fancier than you're currently doing because your database columns don't really match your text file's data, as far as I can tell. You *really* shouldn't have columns named `val1`, `val2`, etc. because it's then impossible to tell what they actually mean.

Comment: I had a tab in the explode to separate the data. I did that to make sure that my data would separate nicely, and it worked out quite nicely. I have not heard of that preg_split command, ill take a peek at it. i just started learning how to do this a week ago so new information is always good

Comment: Those values do have different names but i changed them because of the project that im involved in. I got this whole project dumped on me and im scrambling to play catch up and try and just get this database to read this file so we can do a testing server. No one understands that as a Graphic Designer i have limited code knowledge. I can design things and make them look great, but i cant always get them to work properly. I look to much more code savy people to do that, but i was told NO and my budget got so cheap that i had to do more than normal.

Comment: you're definitely getting there. feel free to mail me on bobbyjack at gmail dot com if you want some one-to-one help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me you're trying to `explode()` your line string using a space as a delimiter.  But that's not how it's put together according to your question.

Here's a line string, with numbers showing how it's exploded with a space.

```
 10/01/15-20:37:30 = 40.2,25.4,42.3,54.3,70.0,66.6
 00000000000000000 1 22222222222222222222222222222
```

Perhaps you want a sequence of two `explode()` calls:

```
    $a = explode (' = ', $line_of_text);
    $vals = explode(',' $a[1]);
```

That will break up your line like so

```
 10/01/15-20:37:30 = 40.2,25.4,42.3,54.3,70.0,66.6
 00000000000000000   11111111111111111111111111111
                     0000 1111 2222 3333 4444 5555
```

At the end of both these `explode()` calls you'll have a $vals array with your six numbers in it.  Then you can do your insert like this.

```
INSERT INTO reading
       (tstamp, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6)
VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s',?), ?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

You can bind `$a[0]` -- the timestamp from your observation line -- to the first `?` placeholder, and the six elements of `$vals` to the rest of the placeholders.

**Edit** OK, let's talk about placeholders. They go with [`bind_param()` in MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php). Read up on that. Seriously.

Your code might look something like this:

```
$linecount = 0; 

$file_handle = fopen("datalog.txt", "r");
while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
    $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
    $a = explode (' = ', $line_of_text);
    $vals = explode(',' $a[1]);

    if ($linecount == 0) {
        /* rig up your SQL statement, just once */
        $sql = "INSERT INTO reading (tstamp, val1, val2, val3, val4, val5, val6) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('%m/%d/%y %H:%i:%s',?), ?,?,?,?,?,?)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bind_param('dssssss', $a[0], $vals[0],$vals[1],$vals[2],$vals[3],$vals[4],$vals[5]);
    }
    if (!$stmt->execute()) {
         printf("Error: %s.\n", $stmt->error);
    }
    $linecount++;
}

$stmt->close();
```

Please note: I haven't had a chance to debug this code; if you use it that's left to you.

Comment: WOW! okay this looks interesting. I understand the two explodes, that makes sense. I get confused at showing the numbers in my VALUES area after the explode. The STR_TO_DATE kinda makes sense but the questions marks are throwring me. Im sorry for the hand holding, im very very new at this. I do very much appreciate everyone's help

Comment: Thank you for giving me an idea of where to run. I will play with this as well. I appreciate the code snippet and i appreciate the help you have given. i will certainly look into bind param. I may have a couple more questions on the though process but this helps